# Glassfish admin console is blank after login

Tags: glassfish

GlassFish admin console is blank after login.

In log file there is 2 messages:

> 1. "User [] from host 127.0.0.1 does not have administration access"
> 2. "SEC5054: Certificate has expired:"

Does anyone know why I am getting blank page?